# Puppeteer - How can I get the current page (application/pdf) as a buffer or file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, buffer, puppeteer

Using Puppeteer (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), I have a page that's a ***application/pdf***. With `headless: false`, the page is loaded though the Chromium PDF viewer, but I want to use headless. How can I download the original .pdf file or use as a blob with another library, such as (pdf-parse https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Puppeteer does not currently support navigation to a PDF document in headless mode via [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) due to the [upstream issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=761295), you can use [`page.setRequestInterception()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) to enable request interception, and then you can listen for the [`'request'`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-request) event and detect whether the resource is a PDF before using the request client to obtain the PDF buffer.

After obtaining the PDF buffer, you can use [`request.abort()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestaborterrorcode) to abort the original Puppeteer request, or if the request is not for a PDF, you can use [`request.continue()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestcontinueoverrides) to continue the request normally.

**Here's a full working example:**

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const request_client = require('request-promise-native');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.url().endsWith('.pdf')) {
      request_client({
        uri: request.url(),
        encoding: null,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'applcation/pdf',
        },
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response); // PDF Buffer
        request.abort();
      });
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
  });

  await page.goto('https://example.com/hello-world.pdf').catch(error => {});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Grant Miller's solution didn't work for me because I was logged in the website. But if the pdf is public this solution works out well.

The solution for my case was to add the cookies

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', async request => {
    if (request.url().indexOf('exibirFat.do')>0) { //This condition is true only in pdf page (in my case of course)
      const options = {
        encoding: null,
        method: request._method,
        uri: request._url,
        body: request._postData,
        headers: request._headers
      }
      /* add the cookies */
      const cookies = await page.cookies();
      options.headers.Cookie = cookies.map(ck => ck.name + '=' + ck.value).join(';');
      /* resend the request */
      const response = await request_client(options);
      //console.log(response); // PDF Buffer
      buffer = response;
      let filename = 'file.pdf';
      fs.writeFileSync(filename, buffer); //Save file
   } else {
      request.continue();
   }
});
```